# При нажатии на CheckBox помещенный в item RecyclerView виджет перестает отображаться

Tags: android, android-layout

есть вот такой layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

есть layout itema'а:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Прогнозист"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlueText"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/rss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite1"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite1"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/remove"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite1"
            android:checked="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

При нажатии на любой CheckBox или если установить его из адаптера нажатым от исчезает, а при повторном нажатии появится.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: На будушее используйте на девайсе Настройки > Для разработчиков > Показывать границы элементов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в теме, используемой приложением что-то не так с `button` для `Checkbox`. У нее разные `state` должны быть для чекнутой и нечекнутой, и видимо один из них неправильный (чекнутый). Попробуйте поменять тему приложения